# How to include special character in a jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

When i do a sed in my jenkinsfile as

```
"sh "sed -i 's|HEAP=.*|HEAP="\-Xms1024m \-Xmx1024m"|' $DIR/bin/myfile"
```

> i get the error as unexpected char :'\'.

How to specify special characters in a jenkinsfile??

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
"""sh sed -i 's|HEAP=.*|HEAP="\-Xms1024m \-Xmx1024m"|' $DIR/bin/myfile"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the \ character to escape a character.